# Python mariadb connector returns datetime.datetime

Tags: python, mariadb, mysql-python

I am writing a script to query mariadb database which returns query output like this
`('101', datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 27, 14, 8, 39), datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 27, 14, 8, 39)`
instead I want output like this
`('101', '2023-01-27 14:08:39.399', 0, '2023-01-27 14:08:39.399')`

```
try:
    conn = mariadb.connect()
except mariadb.Error as e:
    print(f"Error connecting to MariaDB Platform: {e}")
    sys.exit(1)

# Get Cursor
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM <table>")
myresult = cur.fetchall()
print(myresult)
cur.close()
```

I had gotten similar issue when trying with pyodbc so I used my custom output converter but I didn't find any for this library
here's how i did it in pyodbc

```
`  
    # function to convert datetime.date(2022, 10, 12) with data type date to string
    def convert_date_to_string(raw_bytes):
        tup = struct.unpack('3h', raw_bytes)
        return datetime.date(tup[0], tup[1], tup[2]).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    conn.add_output_converter(po.SQL_TYPE_DATE, convert_date_to_string)
```

Kindly suggest a similar approach for maraidb connector as I don't want add parser for every query I make instead I want to do something global like one mentioned aboved as in pyodbc.

Comment: if its only about displaying and not changeing the data type: cursor objects normally (can) use a row_factory. Look for the base class and how to set it (might be done on the connection) and extend the class with a custom one and custom `__str__` function that handles your datatime objects. Similar write your own (named)tuple-like wrapping class for the returned result for printing purposes.

Comment: @Daraan I want to change type also because the code I am working is written to process str datatype as it was written for sqlite and I am porting it to mariadb, one more question should I use mysql connector instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the default behavior in database driver that a database value will be converted to the corresponding python data type.

If you need to convert it into another value, you can either do that on SQL level by using `CAST` function

```
>>> cursor.execute("select cast(now() as char)")
>>> cursor.fetchone()
('2023-02-19 14:42:51',)
```

or by using a converter:

```
>>> import mariadb
>>> from mariadb.constants import FIELD_TYPE
>>> 
>>> def date_to_str(date):
...   return str(date)
... 
>>> conversions= {
...     **{FIELD_TYPE.DATETIME: date_to_str}
... }
>>> 
>>> conn= mariadb.connect(converter=conversions)
>>> cursor=conn.cursor()
>>> cursor.execute("SELECT NOW()")
>>> cursor.fetchone()
('2023-02-19 14:50:29',)
```